# How can I get the context of a class (non-activity) in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, class, android-context

I have come across this question on StackOverflow but I can't use the solutions suggested. One of the most common solutions was to extend the Application class but I can't do that because the class I am in already extends another class. Is there any other way of getting the context of a class?

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
         .......
         .......
         CreateDB dc = new CreateDB(mcontext);
         dc.addBook(new Book(senderPhoneNumber,ang));

}
```

Basically, I need to receive a message and add the sender's number and the message to a database and I need to get the context to create an instance of the database. I am a beginner in android so it would be great if you could keep the language simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you extends BroadCastReceiver you have to add this method

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

}
```

as you can see there is a context in the parameter

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that I could use the same context and was trying to create a constructor which was resulting in my app crashing all the time.

Comment: I am a newbie on StackOverflow and am apparently not allowed to accept an answer shortly after asking it.. I will definitely do so when it allows me..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Context` from `onReceive()` method as follows...

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    CreateDB dc = new CreateDB(context);
    dc.addBook(new Book(senderPhoneNumber,ang));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From  `Activity` in your `application`  you can access the `Contex`t of the `activity`. In your class by using a static reference for example
In you activity class create a static reference

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public static Context mContext;

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public static void setContext(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
}
```

and just pass it in your SMSReceiver class like this

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
         .......
         .......
         CreateDB dc = new CreateDB(MyActivity.getContext());
         dc.addBook(new Book(senderPhoneNumber,ang));

}
```

Comment: I have tried that.. apparently you cannot have a context that is static.. Using the above method gives an error : "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper"

Comment: Yes you are right then you can use a get and set method see my edited answer.

Comment: I was able to run the program after removing static from the setContext() you suggested but it gave a runtime exception..

Comment: can you put off the log cat messages.